# Acumatica. System License Owner Information

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way to get information about **the license owner** in Acumatica?
I found out that there is a **PX.SM.LicenseInfo** DAC which is being initialized by **PX.SM.LicensingSetup.GetLicense(string licenseKey,PXLicenseReason reason)** function but it's private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PXLicenseHelper.License should have what you need. Try one of the following:

- PXLicenseHelper.License.CompanyName
- PXLicenseHelper.License.CustomerName